# How do I pass in Angular mat dialog box width and height?

Tags: css, angular, modal-dialog, mat-dialog

I have this Mat dialog box in Angular and I understand I should pass in the styles for width and height alongside that object but I can't manage to figure out how, it keeps throwing errors. Or is there any other way to set width and height? Thank you

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GroupChooseComponent, {data: {variant} });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add width or height like this according to latest version of Angular Material.

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(GroupChooseComponent, {
    width: '500px',
    height: '500px'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1**

you can't change the height or width because the library fixes the size based on { lg, sm, md }
that's my code ( in my project ), it works for me, you can follow the similar like that

```
this.modalRef = this.modalService.open(UploadUserComponent, { size: 'lg' });
```

**Solution 2**

You can create individual css file to customize the style width or height like you want.